# Google transit is too idealistic. How would you change that?

Tags: algorithm, traffic

Suppose you want to get from point A to point B. You use Google Transit directions, and it tells you:

```
Route 1:
1. Wait 5 minutes
2. Walk from point A to Bus stop 1 for 8 minutes
3. Take bus 69 till stop 2 (15 minues)
4. Wait 2 minutes
5. Take bus 6969 till stop 3(12 minutes)
6. Walk 7 minutes from stop 3 till point B for 3 minutes.
```

Total time = 5 wait + 40 minutes.

```
Route 2:
1. Wait 10 minutes
2. Walk from point A to Bus stop I for 13 minutes
3. Take bus 96 till stop II (10 minues)
4. Wait 17 minutes
5. Take bus 9696 till stop 3(12 minutes)
6. Walk 7 minutes from stop 3 till point B for 8 minutes.
```

Total time = 10 wait + 50 minutes.

All in all Route 1 looks way better. However, what really happens in practice is that bus 69 is 3 minutes behind due to traffic, and I end up missing bus 6969. The next bus 6969 comes at least 30 minutes later, which amounts to 5 wait + 70 minutes (including 30 m wait in the cold or heat). Would not it be nice if Google actually advertised this possibility? My question now is: what is the better algorithm for displaying the top 3 routes, given uncertainty in the schedule?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take uncertainty into account then there is no longer a "best route", but instead there can be a "best strategy" that minimizes the total time in transit; however, it can't be represented as a linear sequence of instructions but is more of the form of a general plan, i.e. "go to bus station X, wait until 10:00 for bus Y, if it does not arrive walk to station Z..." This would be notoriously difficult to present to the user (in addition of being computationally expensive to produce).

For a fixed sequence of instructions it is possible to calculate the probability that it actually works out; but what would be the level of certainty users want to accept? Would you be content with, say, 80% success rate? When you then miss one of your connections the house of cards falls down in the worst case, e.g. if you miss a train that leaves every second hour.

I wrote many years a go a similar program to calculate long-distance bus journeys in Finland, and I just reported the transfer times assuming every bus was on schedule. Then basically every plan with less than 15 minutes transfer time or so was disregarded because they were too risky (there were sometimes only one or two long-distance buses per day at a given route).

Answer (score 3):

How about adding weightings that express a level of uncertainty for different types of journey elements.

Bus services in Dublin City are notoriously untimely, you could add a 40% margin of error to anything to do with Dublin Bus schedule, giving a best & worst case scenario. you could also factor in the chronic traffic delays at rush hours. Then a user could see that they may have a 20% or 80% chance of actually making a connection.

You could sort "best" journeys by the "most probably correct" factor, and include this data in the results shown to the user.

My two cents :)

Answer (score 2):

For the UK rail system, each interchange node has an associated 'minimum transfer time to allow'. The interface to the route planner [here](http://ojp.nationalrail.co.uk/en/s/planjourney/query) then has an Advanced option allowing the user to either accept the default, or add half hour increments.

In your example, setting a' minimum transfer time to allow' of say 10 minutes at step 2 would prevent Route 1 as shown being suggested. Of course, this means that the minimum possible journey time is increased, but that's the trade off.

Answer (score 1):

Empirically. Record the actual arrival times vs scheduled arrival times, and compute the mean and standard deviation for each. When considering possible routes, calculate the probability that a given leg will arrive late enough to make you miss the next leg, and make the average wait time `P(on time)*T(first bus) + (1-P(on time))*T(second bus)`. This gets more complicated if you have to consider multiple legs, each of which could be late independently, and multiple possible next legs you could miss, but the general principle holds.

Answer (score 1):

Catastrophic failure should be the first check.

This is especially important when you are trying to connect to that last bus of the day which is a critical part of the route.  The rider *needs* to know that is what is happening so he doesn't get too distracted and knows the risk.

After that it could evaluate worst-case single misses.

And then, if you really wanna get fancy, take a look at the crime stats for the neighborhood or transit station where the waiting point is.